# Why don't Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework v4 get installed?

Tags: fxcop

I have a Windows 7 64-bit computer with [Visual Studio 2008](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2008) and Visual Studio 2010 Professional installed (C# only).

Now I want [FxCop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FxCop). I read first we should install Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 4, so I wanted to do so, but it gives me error and says installation failed, go find more details in some HTML page in a folder path that it does not even exist:

> Installation of the “Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7″ product has reported the following error: Please refer to Samples\Setup\HTML\ConfigDetails.htm document for further information.

So two questions:

1. I do not care about the rest of the stuff. I just want FxCop! Do I really need to install this SDK too?
2. What do you think is the problem when its installation fails?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a very similar problem. You don't need to install the SDK to do it. However, you still need to download it which is unfortunate as it is a pretty large download after all. Why it isn't a separate download is beyond me...

Anyway, I extracted the install files I needed by following the information in *[XXX](http://blogx.co.uk/ViewItem.asp?Entry=812)*.

In brief, you need to do this (edited from the link above):

> Download the ISO version instead, extract it with 7Zip and locate
>   Setup\WinSDKNetFxTools\cab1.cab. Open it with Windows and copy out the
>   file
>   "WinSDK_FxCopSetup.exe_all_enu_1B2F0812_3E8B_426F_95DE_4655AE4DA6C6".
>   Rename this to "WinSDK_FxCopSetup.exe" and it should now install.

You can also browse the [ISO image](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_image) with suitable tools rather than unextracting the whole thing.

Given the date of this post, you might have already found the solution, but it may help others who come acros this issue.

From the page above there is a comment linking to another explanation that is better detailed: *[Liberate FxCop 10.0](http://ruthlesslyhelpful.net/2011/06/09/liberate-fxcop-10-0/)*.

Comment: +1; and it wouldn't hurt if the contents of that blog (at least the most important part, the path to the installation file in the iso) were repeated in this answer. Just in case the website gets disabled or restructured at some point, and the link stops working.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper Thanks for the comment, I have done exactly what you suggested.